# Vimscript - run normal! qm after running normal! @m

Tags: plugins, editor, vim

So, this is a weird situation I've run into while trying to write a plugin. It looks like a bug in Vim to me, but I might be missing something, so I've turned to the wisdom of StackOverflow.

Take this function:

```
fun! Test()
    normal! q ; Stop recording a macro.
    let @r='kkkkkkkkkkkkk'
    normal! @r
    normal! qm
endf
```

Basically, I stop recording a macro, try and run the contents of a register, then start re-recording a macro.

I call this function by hitting `qm`, doing some commands, then calling the function.

**What I expect**

I expect the "kkkkkk" to be execute, and then recording to start again.

**What Happens**

The "kkkk" is run, but recording is *not* started again.

I don't understand  why!

**Workaround**

The following function does what I want, but it's a hack. I'm trying to understand the root cause of my problem:

fun! Test()
    normal! q
    let @r='kkkkkkkkkkkkk'
    execute "normal! " . @r 
    normal! qm
endf

I just replaced the running of the register with an execute call that directly executes the contents of the register. I tricked vim into not thinking it is running a register, basically.

**Note: Why I want this**

It's for a plugin. This function is simply the smallest I could make that exhibits a problem. Not worth getting into why I want this - the basic functionality I needed was to run a register from within a function, then start recording it again. In the actual use case, the register I run and record to is the same, but it didn't seem to affect this issue.

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Why can’t you just embed the function call inside a mapping:

```
function Test()
    let @r='kkkkkkkkkkkk'
    normal! @r
endfunction
nnoremap Q q:call Test()<CR>qm
```

? If “m” is actually a non-constant value then you have to use `<expr>`:

```
nnoremap <expr> Q "q:call Test()\nq".g:plugin_register
```

. You can, of course, use a function call inside an `<expr>` mapping (thus moving `normal! @r` to the outputs of function: `return '@r'` because expression is not allowed to do `normal!`, buffer editing, switching and moving the cursor around).

Comment: Firstly, I don't recognize the "q:call" syntax, what does that do? Second, right now the function does a lot of other things, logically the "qm" is part of the function. Thirdly, the function is actually called with "au CursorMoved :call MyFunction()<cr>", i.e. is called every time the cursor moves. But inside, it has a check to see that the plugin is actually enabled, and the "qm" should only be done if the plugin is enabled. So I'm not sure this is the way to go...

Comment: @EdanMaor 1. Just what `normal! q` was supposed to do. 2. If it is a CursorMoved event that you are not likely to do much of the kind of side effects (at least if you follow the advice from help) that are forbidden to be done from `<expr>` (though finishing recording a macro actually *is* that kind of side-effect). You ought to be able to translate it to an `<expr>`-mapping rhs capable function. The key point of using mapping (likely a `<Plug>` one) and calling it with `feedkeys()` from an event is to workaround the problem you pointed out. 3. Just return an empty string in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little unclear as to what the problem is exactly. I also didn't know feedkeys, but don't understand from the docs how it differs from doing "normal @r", where register "r" holds the keys I want executed.

Comment: Btw, what I'm trying to do is build a "multi-cursor" mode for vim, where I mark different places in the buffer, then can execute every command I do automatically on them (including moving the cursor left, right, etc.). That's what the whole mapping is about. As of this point, I got the core functionality working with my method "workaround", and I'm asking now mostly to understand what I'm missing - I understand my solution and yours, but I don't understand why the original way the function was written doesn't work.

Comment: @EdanMaor I can’t say why it does not work (not without digging with a source code backed by a debugger), but why have you come up to using register here at all, especially after you had been forced to use `:execute`? You can assign this value to just any other local variable. You should get more help on vim-dev if you post this as a bug (which seems to be true).

Comment: The basic thing I'm doing is executing the same movement in X different places. So the way it works is, I start recording a macro into a register, then, on every movement, loop through all the X points, and run the macro there, then start recording again. This is the basic flow of the code. Does that make sense? I'm not certain that this is the best way to do this, but it's the only one I've come up with.

Comment: @EdanMaor Indeed, it does. I would’ve used `getchar()` (especially after I already have code that uses `getchar()` to capture user’s input in order to pretend a user can execute something simultaneously with some other highly time-consuming processing’s done), but I tend to prefer solutions that don’t use `normal!` and friends. `getchar()` here has a major drawback of not showing the cursor position which is distracting (in my case when processing is done though it does not matter: the cursor is not going to be shown anyway) and I don’t have another good solution to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I thought about GetChar(), but I don't think I could use it. I need to get characters, then perform their action in a few different places. It works well if I get a movement command, but if I get a command like "dw" (i.e., an operator-pending command), then trying to run "d" and "w" one by one seperately will not work. Then again, I'm running with "normal", which is the only way I know. Is there another way?

Comment: @EdanMaor If you are looking for the `getchar()`-based solution you may look at [s:iterfuncs.csshow.next](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum/src/74e509f08f84/plugin/aurum/log.vim#cl-570) function, but it has only limited support for operators (and no at all for `g@`) and has a drawback of not displaying a cursor if you change it to request input, not wait for the one. But here I have no possible way I can use macros or like: this function is to be executed between the steps of generating buffer contents (and only because this is slow).

Comment: @EdanMaor All it has for processing multicharacter commands is a bunch of workarounds which are going to break when some mode-switching mappings (including ones that use `g@` to switch to operator-pending mode) are present. It is generally not a good way to implement any user-input handling functionality, but it is all I can do under my circumstances. I think I know a way to add support for mappings ending in other modes (though it is going to get clumsy and suspend my calculations).

Comment: @EdanMaor I can post the explanation of the latter here if you are interested, but now it seems your solution is better for your problem. Just not anything I could’ve thought about after writing a bunch of plugins that do not require that sort of action and thus’ve used to thinking of avoiding potentially unneeded and/or unexpected side-effects that almost every `:normal`/`feedkeys()`-based solution is going to invoke.